# Is there such a thing as a modern cable modem without an onboard operating system?

Tags: network, firmware

Is there such a thing as a modern cable modem without an onboard operating system? I’m looking for examples of specific models, in particular.

Every modem I’ve looked at has a Web interface (e.g., the Arris SB6141 and the Netgear CM1000), which suggests to me that they all have an onboard Linux operating system installed that can be hacked and reconfigured to maliciously route traffic like a router.

(I imagine that all modems are going to involve some kind of firmware, but I also imagine that it doesn’t need to be a whole operating system.)

Comment: There's not really this hard distinction between a "full operating system" and "firmware".  At the very least a cable modem is going to need a TCP/IP stack to be able to receive and route packets.  I wouldn't make the assumption that the lack of web interface, or running on a more limited operating system makes the machine somehow unhackable.  It's still software, and software is hackable.

Comment: For instance, even a hard drive can become infected with malware.  https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/equation-hdd-malware/7623/ Whether the software on the HDD is an "operating system" is mostly irrelevant because you're interested in hackability, not semantics.

Comment: not anymore. General purpose fast CPUs became so cheap that's it's not economically viable to design custom hardware to handle tasks that can be completed by software and "chips". Same with Nintendo: early models had hardware to, for example, generate triangle waves without "hogging" limited CPU time, but as chips got faster, all that is done at a much higher level using hardware not too dissimilar to a consumer PC. The real distinction for you to make these days is between an OS (like linux) and a RTOS, which will be much less exploitable with known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have some X/Y conflicts in your reasoning behind the question.

1. Modems do not need an operating system. What you are calling a modem (with a web interface) is far more than a modem, which requires an "operating system".
2. The operating system you are supposing is not a "whole operating system" but an embedded form of an operating system (likely with a custom kernel) to supply the necessary functions.
3. The operating system is not "hacked" in your threat scenario, but rather the externally-facing services are.

So, with these reframing points in mind: There have been many different cable modems without the extra features like the ones you listed. The problem is that they only allow a single device to connect to it, so they have not been a popular product since adding a hub, WiFi, and NAT functionality have become the norm.

That last point is the practical one. If you were able to find a dumb cable modem, you would need to attach a multi-function WiFi access point, router, hub, and a means to manage these features. So, what do you do? You chain the modem (basically a layer 1/2 device) to the router (layers 2+). Now you have exactly the same threats as you did before, but you now need to buy an extra device for the privilege.

Want to limit your risk with your existing modem? Turn off all services to the Internet, put in a very long admin password, and turn on the highest security for the Wifi.

Comment: With regard to (1), this seems accurate, but what the market is calling "cable modems" to contrast with their more expensive "cable router" offerings appear to be referring to basic "routers" in practice (which, if universally the case, means that there's no security advantage to buying a "modem" ("router-lite") over a "router" since they're the same thing). I was wondering if there are any "true" modems on the market which I would expect to just be a piece of hardware that transparently relays traffic using minimal software. Instead, they all appear to be running Linux with all of its risks.

Comment: I certainly have not seen a "dumb modem" in many, many (many) years. In a previous life, I used to do home installations of the first cable modems in an experimental market. Because of the lack of multi-use functionality, I really do not expect that there would be any on the market.

Comment: Because the modems need to be supplied by the telco, it is really up to them and their capabilities. Modern telcos offer Internet, TV, and phone over the cable, so all that needs some level of OS to function.